# ORA-01086: savepoint 'L_SAVEPOINT' never established in this session or is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql, savepoints

In my case, savepoint was set in Java and I am trying to rollback in a plsql procedure which was called in Java using a callable statement.

There are no commits or rollbacks in between, but I am still seeing the error:

> **ORA-01086**: savepoint 'L_SAVEPOINT' never established in this session
>   or is invalid

Is it because the savepoint is set in Java and I am trying to rollback in plsql? 
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: How do you set the savepoint from java? Show us your code.

Comment: Are you sure this is all in the same session; and there hasn't been an *auto*commit in between (as the savepoint and PL/SQL call are, presumably, two separate calls to the DB)?

Comment: Looks like, java and plsql procedure are considered as 2 different transactions. Issue got fixed for me when I set the savepoint inside the PL/SQL procedure and rollback also inside the procedure.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. You can answer your own question with the information in your comment, then accept your answer.  Doing this will help others find a good solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and plsql procedure are considered as 2 different transactions. Issue got fixed for me when I set the savepoint inside the PL/SQL procedure and rollback also inside the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing some light on this, My colleague experienced the similar issue when he controls the transaction but I had a commit inside the stored procedure. Remove the Commit/Rollback from the SP and you should be all set if you want to control the transaction from Java.